# Gamma(e)=Pi/2,Zeta(e)=4/Pi ?

Tags: special-functions

I find that Gamma(e) is close to Pi/2 and Zeta(e) is close to 4/Pi. So I have a question:

$\Gamma (e) = \pi /2$

$\zeta (e) = 4/\pi $

Is it true in fact?

Answer (score 3):

Maple says $\Gamma(e)=1.567468255$, $\pi/2=1.570796327$, $\zeta(e)=1.269009604$, $4/\pi=1.273239544$.

Comment: what is the precision of the result Gamma(e)=1.567468255, zeta(e)=1.269009604?

Comment: @a-boy, more than enough to show that your proposed equations do not hold. Maple's numerics are good enough that I would trust all those values to be off by at most 1 in the last given decimal place. I just realized that your screen name makes this comment start "atta boy"! 